# Vector size reduction preserving dot product

Tags: python, vector, dimensionality-reduction, dot-product, rescale

I have Vectors with size n=1000..3000 which have a mean=0 and std-dev=1/sqrt(n) and length/norm=1.

My question is what formula, algorithm I can use to reduce the vectors size but preserve the **DOT product similarity** i.e. after re-scaling the dot product between any 2 vectors should be approximately the same as the original vectors ?

---

random selection seems to work:

% : normalizes the operands and does the DOT product..

```
In [34]: ab % bc
Out[34]: 0.445

In [35]: ab[::2] % bc[::2]
Out[35]: 0.424

In [36]: ab[::3] % bc[::3]
Out[36]: 0.440

In [39]: rnd = np.random.randint(0,1000,300)

In [40]: ab[rnd] % bc[rnd]
Out[40]: 0.450
```

Comment: You want to reduce the vector dimension, or the vector length?

Comment: f.e. from n=1000 to n=500

Comment: This can’t be done independently of the vector values, since any continuous projection will cause some very different vectors to become identical.

Comment: what if i have all the  vectors

Comment: @sten: Do you have more vectors than dimensions?

Comment: 10 000 to 100 000 vectors

Comment: (If you don’t use `@`, your reply may go unnoticed.)  This is impossible in general: consider reducing the 3 3D elementary unit vectors to 2D, where the most orthogonal 3 vectors can be is -1/2.  Are you intending to rely on more convenient vectors than that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246513/discussion-between-sten-and-davis-herring).